# Adding eventListener to Submit-Button in a Form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a submit button to send the form data to the next page. So far so good. But now there should be some javascript-code executed (for tracking reasons) when the user submits the form. So I tried to set an event-listener. Problem is: sometimes the code will execute and sometimes it will be ignored.

I set a timeout and figured out that all timeouts greater than 15ms won't execute the code and to browser is already on the form_test.html page.

```js
//secTimeout = 15;
button = document.getElementById('submitbutton');
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // setTimeout(function(){
  //   console.log('log after ' + secTimeout + 'ms');
  // }, secTimeout);

  // execute tracking tool
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="form_test.html">
  <input type="text" name="text1">
  <input type="text" name="text2">
  <input type="text" name="text3">
  <input type="submit" id="submitbutton">
</form>
```

what would be a good proceeding to ensure to js-code will run every time?

Comment: Don't set a timeout, just run the code directly. Or you can attach the code to the form's submit function, preventDefault on the submission event, and then trigger a manual submit when your code is done? Generally speaking, though, if you have to wait for a delay only after a form is submitted, run code, and then expect the form to submit normally, you're probably designing your code flow wrong.

Comment: The better way is remove the submit button from the form and use a normal button. Or, you can try use preventDefault: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to add tracking functionnality is to handle the submission programmaticaly. So use a  and get inspiration from [this](http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml). By sending the form programmaticaly you can run any piece of code you want before sending.

A small example:

```
<form id="form1" action="form_test.html">
  <input type="text" name="text1">
  <input type="text" name="text2">
  <input type="text" name="text3">
  <button id="submitbutton">
</form>


button = document.getElementById('submitbutton');
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // execute tracking tool
  document.form1.submit();
});
```

Comment: thanks, i ended up with a button instead of input type=submit

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is

- you should receive an event parameter in your event-handling function
- then you should prevent default on this event (because generally when
  you press the submit button, it submits the form)
- then you should do your tracking code
- then you should submit the form manually by
  calling submit method of the form